# How to use a mixin in pug.compile()

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I want do something like this:

```
mixin table_row(event)
    tr 
        td=event.name
        td=event.type
        td=event.time
        td=event.venue
        td
            +dropdown(event.id)

script.
    const setEvents = (events) => {
        let tbody = document.getElementById('events-tbody')

        const compile = pug.compile(
            `each event in events` +'\n'+
            `   tr` +'\n'+
            `       +table_row(event)`
        )

        tbody.innerHTML = compile({events})
    }
```

On a button click, I am calling an API that fetches events. I want to display these events in a table using `table_row` mixin that I have already defined in the .pug file.

Right now this code gives an error that `table_row` is not defined. Is there a way for me to pass this mixin in the `pug.compile()` function?

Reference:
https://pugjs.org/api/reference.html#pugcompilesource-options

Comment: Why are you doing this client-side?

Comment: @Sean I'm using express view engine, and I don't want to refresh the page so I'm using javaScript to update this.

Comment: The HTML that is sent to the browser has no knowledge of the Pug from which it was compiled—so of course `table_row` isn't defined. Instead of trying to compile Pug client-side, you could make an AJAX request to an express route that queries the API, passes the data to Pug and compiles it, then sends the browser the compiled HTML as the response to the request.

Comment: @Sean can you write code for this? Because I'm unable to compile on the server side.

Comment: @InaaraKalani Where is `events` coming from? Do you understand that you are using `pug.compile` in the client, ie browser. Do you really need to do that?